# axis Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl

hi all， I get a exception "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure".

My Environment:

```
JDK: jdk1.7.0_80
weblogic:10.3.6
axsi:1.4
```

What I do:

```
1. add certificate to truststore.
2.install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7.
3.set start Arguments:
  -Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS1
  -Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2
  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
(and I have enable JSSE SSL)
4. set TLS1.2 in code where have use axis

  context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
  context.init(null, null, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

now it alaways show "handshake_failure" exception.
and in the log files,i found the follow info. i guess that the TSL1.2 not enable. But in other requests, it used TLS1.2.
Do you have any ideas?

```
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```